# Strategy for applying to a company where I'm not sure of the role I'd best serve in?

Tags: software-industry, resume, applications

I'm a software engineer hoping to transition into UX. I've done a very short basics course, but as yet don't have a portfolio to show (and would be far away from being able to produce one given the workload).

Prior to all of the above, I trained to be a classical musician.

I've just found a company I'd love to apply for which would allow me to combine all these interests - the problem is I'm not sure how to frame my application. They seem to be on something of a hiring binge with a lot of roles open:

- There's a UX/UI designer role open which doesn't specify seniority
- There's a strictly more musically-oriented role open
- There is also a speculative application open, which I assume I could apply though as an engineer

It's worth noting that I would be happy in any of these roles, regardless of compensation. I just want to work here!

**My question is this: what is the best path to follow to get in the door of a company if you have a broad skill-set that could fit many of their positions?** Send in an open application telling them this, and leave it to them to decide? Or be specific, follow one route and tell them of my intention to transition down the line? Or another path?

Comment: If you would be happy with any of those, then you should do some self-analysis, decide what you *really* want and go for that.

Comment: How big is this company? You might be able to get by with a broad application at a small shop, but not something much bigger.

Comment: Wait, what is UX? Did I miss something?

Comment: User eXperience @SandraK

Comment: Is it possible to contact someone at the company informally, prior to submitting a formal application? Sometimes the recruiter can suggest which role sounds like the best fit. What is a "speculative application"?

Comment: How is your progress? Share it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the best path to follow to get in the door of a company if you have a broad skill-set that could fit many of their positions?

I think you got several options. One is to **decide what role you like the most and go for that**. To do this you will have to do some self-analysis to find which path is that; it is your career and you should do what interests *you*.

Other, as you mentioned, is to send **a broader/open application indicating your interest in those areas**. To this you will have to be thoughtful when tailoring your resume and application material, as a jack-of-all-trades may or may not be what they are looking for; your application has to show a wider experience, but with enough detail on each part (otherwise it may seem as you are "master of none" of those trades).

You can also **apply to all three roles separately**, tailoring your application to better fit each one. This way perhaps gives you more maneuvering space on the choice you have to make further down the recruitment process.

As a side comment, it seems to me that if they are indeed in such hiring bridge then a candidate like you surely will be highly interesting. You should take advantage of such opportunity, think and make a choice, and go for it.